# Core 2 / Typescript Response Errors

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to do validation on server side and I want the code to return a response with the error message and error code why the server refused it.

```
public IActionResult AddAdvertisement([FromBody]AdvertisementModel model)
{
    bool validModel = true;
    string ErrorMessage = "";

    AdvertisementModel PostModel = model;

    if (PostModel.category == 0)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Category can't be 0";
        validModel = false;
        JsonResult s = new JsonResult(ErrorMessage);
        s.StatusCode = 654;
        return s;
    }
```

The furthest I got, but I cannot read the response body text as error message in typescript:
[image]

Maybe I am handling this wrong? Any ideas to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As as improvement , create your own status code [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.statuscodes?view=aspnetcore-2.2) , try to do the following</strike>

```
if (PostModel.category == 0)
{
    result = new {
      ErrorMessage = "Category can't be 0", 
      ValidModel = false,
    };
    return StatusCode(654,result);
}
```

Then, this answer should be rejected as error by typescript.

While this approach is applicable , it's not a common way in validations and is out of the [W3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) standard.
It's better to return a BadRequest with status code 400 , and in the result body add your internal code number as follows

```
if (PostModel.category == 0)
{
    result = new {
      ErrorMessage = "Category can't be 0", 
      ValidModel = false,
      Code = 654
    };
    return BadRequest(result);
}
```